# Unable to delete Sharepoint Online term store items programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom, sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft365

I'm trying to delete terms or term sets from the default taxonomy store in a C# application which authenticates with an Azure App. I've tried using certificate and app secret authentication as well as a user account context. Using the certificate/app secret, the authentication is successful and I can read terms but receive an error when I try to delete a term:

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerUnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.'

Tried this using both using CSOM and PnP Framework. The App has full read and write permissions for the SharePoint API and Graph API relating to SharePoint/Term Store.

Using user account, I get an error that the login/password could not be found. MFA is disabled for this account in 365 Admin, but it seems the web portal still asks for this to be set up when logging in via browser.

Using the MS Graph API and the same Azure App, I can also create terms, but Graph does not support deleting terms at the moment so this method cannot be used.